# Merging 3 columns into 1 in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm having a problem to merge three columns into 1 in MySQL. It's true that I have some null values in some of the columns but I think it makes no difference since at first result it gives me the correct result, but when I browse the table, the 3 columns remain and the new column remains empty. This is the code I have used:

```
SELECT FirstName AS First_Name
 , LastName AS Last_Name
 , CONCAT_WS('', ContactPhoneAreaCode1, ContactPhoneNumber1, ContactPhoneNumber1) AS Contact_Phone 
FROM TABLE1
```

Comment: You are just selecting a calculation. Did you mean to alter the table's structure?

Comment: I don't mind to alter the table structure as long as I have a column merging the three.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to actually alter the table:

1. In phpmyadmin or using an ALTER TABLE command, add the ContactPhone column
2. `UPDATE MyTable SET ContactPhone = CONCAT_WS('', ContactPhoneAreaCode1, ContactPhoneNumber1, ContactPhoneNumber1)` to insert desired values (did you really mean to have ContactPhoneNumber1 twice in there?)
3. And perhaps write a trigger so that when future rows are added, or existing rows have the area code or phone number changed, the ContactPhone column is automatically updated

But a much better approach is to create a VIEW on your TABLE that has this extra column:

`CREATE VIEW MyVIEW AS SELECT *, CONCAT_WS('', ContactPhoneAreaCode1, ContactPhoneNumber1, ContactPhoneNumber1) AS ContactPhone from MyTable`

Then you can use the view just like you used the table, but it has an extra synthesized column that never needs to be kept in sync.

Comment: ContactPhoneAreaCode1, was just a copy and paste, actually are 2 different columns. I tried your second approach, it gives success in phpmyadmin but the when I brows everything remains the same

Comment: Your first approach resulted ok. Thank you!

Comment: One more question, I have about 3000 results "null" since this is an import from google contacts, is there a way where I can delete all these rows at once?

Comment: @JoseBorges post a new question about how to delete all the results with 'null' in some column, that's pretty easy and you'll get an answer quickly. If you create the view, then you have to browse the VIEW to see the results. It doesn't modify the original table itself, it creates a 'pseudo-table' with the calculated column that you want.