# How do I create table schema in MySQL which populates data dynamically?

Tags: mysql

I have a `php` page where the user enters the following details

1. Name
2. Age

But in the database, I want to have an additional column that automatically inserts data with the combination of entered data as shown below for Code column.

| Key | Name | Age | Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mike | 28 | MIKE128 |
| 2 | Raj | 32 | RAJ232 |

So I have altered my table as follow

```
   ALTER TABLE Employee ADD COLUMN Code;
   UPDATE Employee  SET Code = CONCAT(Key,Name,Age);
```

But this updates only the existing data for existing data,and shows `NULL` for newly entered data. What is the command I shall use to change the schema so that whenever I add new data automatically it updates the `Code` column

Below is my try, which is failed

```
     CREATE TABLE `Employee` (
        `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `Name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
        `Age` int(2) NOT NULL,
        `Combined` varchar(10) AS (`Name` + `id` +  `Age`) Code,
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
     );
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 2: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Code,
> PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
> )' at line 4

**Note:** I DO NOT want to concate and supply data from the front end.

**Note**: This is just example as I can not post real data.

Comment: Create an insert trigger.

Comment: or use a generated column

Comment: Why bother storing such easily derived data?

Comment: what u mean by easily derived data? The question has only sample data. This is just to understand the concept.

Comment: I have updated the question. Dear downvoter, Kindly share the improvement points so that I can improve the question

Comment: Note that this design violates 1st normal form and is prone to data integrity issues. Better would be to create a view on the base table to get calculated columns. This approach is potentially less performant, if SELECTs are much more frequent than INSERTs and UPDATEs, though the difference may not be an issue in production.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merging 3 columns into 1 in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36811461/merging-3-columns-into-1-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

You can setup trigger for dynamic default value

```
CREATE TRIGGER Employee_code_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON Employee
FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.Code = IFNULL(NEW.Code, CONCAT(NEW.Key, NEW.Name, NEW.Age));
```

Comment: NEW.Key comes as 0, any reason? AUTO_INCREMENT happens post trigger?